# close dialog from componet in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello im trying to close a dialog from the component I try to put the path in .angular-cli.json and call the function but it dont close the dialog and don't redirect

component:

```
declare function closeDialog():any;
export class DemoNotificationComponent implements OnInit   {
constructor(private router: Router) {
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  responder(){
   closeDialog()
   this.router.navigate(['/enviarMensajes']);

  } 
}
```

html:

```
 <dialog #dialog style="width:30%;"id="dialog">
    <div *ngFor="let mensaje of mensajes">{{mensaje.mensaje}}</div>

</dialog>
```

javascript file:

```
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");

function showDialog() {
 dialog.show();
}

function closeDialog() {
 dialog.close();
}
```

I try to close dialog from the component and redirect to an other component

Comment: please complete the class code and describe your exact problem

Comment: The question needs more details. What dialog are you using? Material? Bootstrap? If possible please create a stackblitz with your code and it will be much easier for others to answer your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a `solution` I only have to put the
`const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");`
in the function.
But it still doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

in your javascript file instead of using

```
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
```

use below code

```
const dialog = document.querySelector('dialog').close();
```

Comment: I've tried that but still don't work